# Getting reference to paging textfield in ExtJS4 Grid Panel

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4, javascript-framework

I've look through the API on Sencha's website, googled around, and tinkered with the code, but I just can't find how to get a handle on the textfield in the toolbar. I'd like to bind an event to it. I've tried this so far,

```
Ext.getCmp('numberfield-1028-bodyEl').addListener('activate', function(){
    alert('activated');
});
```

where 'numberfield-1028-bodyEl' is the element id ( I got this from using firebug ). Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reach needed textfield using [down( [String selector] )](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.grid.Panel-method-down) method (the argument is component selector which allows to search needed component by its xtype and by using similar syntax to a CSS selector. More info [here](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.ComponentQuery))

```
var grid = Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', { /* ... */ });

grid.down('pagingtoolbar > textfield').addListener('activate', function(){
    alert('activated');
});
```